# String variable adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var currentClass = ((elementArray[count]['Name'] === entityName) ? "'context-li-current-background'" : "' context-li-item-background-default'");      


"<li id='" + elementArray[count]['Url'] + "'  class='context-li-item '\'' + currentClass +'\''>" + elementArray[count]['Text'] + "</li>";
```

um conditionally trying to add a class to my li element by jquery side, but above code give

```
 <li +'''="" currentclass="" +="" ''="" class="context-li-item " id="/Alphabet/list">Alphabe</li>
```

I found that the class string is breaking here
I do not know how to append the conditionally checked value, It will be a great help if any  one could suggest a way

Comment: use some variable to store this string.

Comment: um not permitted to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create elements using jQuery, much cleaner

```
var li = $('<li></li>')
        .prop('ID', elementArray[count]['Url'])
        .addClass('context-li-item' + currentClass)
        .text(elementArray[count]['Text'])
```

As per your existing implementation use

```
var currentClass = (elementArray[count]['Name'] === entityName) 
    ? " context-li-current-background" //You don't need to use quotes in string
    : " context-li-item-background-default";    

"<li id='" + elementArray[count]['Url'] + "' class='context-li-item " + currentClass + "'>" + elementArray[count]['Text'] + "</li>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately um not allowed to do that :(

Comment: @Kirov why not? you tagged jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You have quoting problems, try with this

```
"<li id='" + elementArray[count]['Url'] + "' class='context-li-item " + currentClass + "'>" + elementArray[count]['Text'] + "</li>";
```

**EDIT**

Something else, remove single quotes here

```
var currentClass = ((elementArray[count]['Name'] === entityName) 
     ? "'context-li-current-background'" 
     : "' context-li-item-background-default'");
```

So you should have

```
var currentClass = ((elementArray[count]['Name'] === entityName) 
     ? "context-li-current-background" 
     : "context-li-item-background-default");
```

Comment: class="context-li-item " context-li-item-background-default''=""> I got this

Comment: @Kirov: added something else to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have mixed up double and single quotes. Use single quotes to define your string, and use double quotes where you need quotes in the output string

```
'<li id="' + elementArray[count]['Url'] + '"  class="context-li-item ' + currentClass +'">'+ elementArray[count]['Text'] + '</li>';
```